# ¿Cómo puede crear mi usuario un objeto en la BD con un unique_key igual al objeto creado por otro usuario?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

mi objetivo es que los usuarios de mi aplicación puedan crearse objetos del siguiente tipo:

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    name = models.ChatField(unique=True)
```

Cada usuario tiene asignado el id del Wallet que haya creado él mismo, por lo que solo podrá ver sus propias wallets, pero como el **name** es único, si un usuario intenta crear un wallet con un nombre que ya exista, dará error.

¿Cómo puedo  hacer para que el usuario no pueda crear un wallet con un nombre que ya exista **de todas las wallets que ha creado él** pero ese nombre pueda existir en una Wallet creada por otro usuario?

Entiendo que habría que quitar el unique=True y supongo que se controlaría por la views o el form de la siguiente forma:

Compruebo de todos los wallets que el usuario se ha creado, si hay alguno que tenga ese nombre, en ese caso, retorno error.

¿Hay alguna otra forma más eficiente?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás podrías almacenar internamente el nombre de la Wallet como: nombre_usuario_nombre_wallet o algo similar.

Sería sólo a nivel de guardarlas. A la hora de que el usuario las visualice, les quitarías el nombre de usuario antes. De igual manera, cuando el usuario cree una nueva, lo escribirá sin su nombre delante y simplemente tú añadirás el nombre antes de guardarla.

Para evitar colisiones con otros nombres de usuario (por ejemplo el usuario "dog" crea una wallet "my_wallet_1" (dog_my_wallet_1) tendríamos que evitar que un posible usuario "dog_my" crease "wallet_1"

Una opción es utilizar un separador que luego no permitas en el nombre de la wallet. Como / o @

Espero haberte entendido y que te sea de ayuda

Comment: Creo que sería mejor almacenar el id del wallet en el usuario y hacer que el campo name no fuese único, de esta forma, recorrería cada id del campo wallets del usuario (donde está almacenado el id) y los mostraría, y no importaría que dos wallets tuviesen el mismo nombre...

Comment: Efectivamente, es una solución más elegante. Pero si quieres que no se pueda repetir la misma wallet para un mismo usuario tendrías que o bien utilizar algo como lo que propongo (añadir algún prefijo al nombre y hacer el nombre único) o utilizar tu sistema pero con una comprobación adicional: cuando se vaya a crear una wallet nueva compruebas el nombre de todas las wallets del usuario para no permitir un nombre duplicado para ese mismo usuario.

Comment: Sí, tienes razón en eso!